# Can a system.xml be overwritten?

Tags: php, xml, magento

Can a core system.xml be overwritten in the same way that a block could, by placing a 'version' of it in the local/ representation of the original directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Official® way to do this is to create a custom module with a `<depends />` declaration for the module with content you wish to override. In the custom module's *system.xml* it is necessary to *only* include *system.xml* those xpaths whose text values you wish to override. This means less work when it comes time to upgrade.

Comment: Ben's got it as usual, but in case it isn't clear you can't replace a `system.xml` by creating a new one in a local code pool.  Magento will  merge those PHP files based on the code pool that's set for the module in app/etc/modules.

Answer (score 1):

No, because you define the code pool of each module in the app/etc/modules/* XML files and the corresponding module files in app/code/code_pool/MODULE/etc/*.xml are loaded with respect to that configuration.

Edit: In contrast, for *.php files you can overwrite, because these are loaded using the autoloader which always checks local before community before core

Edit2: To make it crystal clear: The Magento autoloader is not responsible for Xml files. Therefore, the load precedence of local over community over core does not hold for Xml files. However, you can still edit the Xml by creating a local module which does this as pointed out in benmarks' answer

Comment: Correction, the autoloader doesn't 'check' local first, it loads local last. This means any values for an xpath in local codepool take precedence (sort of like how CSS works). Also, `/app/etc/local.xml` takes precedence over all of them. It is loaded first (to set up DB connection, etc) and then it loads it again at the end (to ensure no modules are modifying DB connection, etc).

Comment: @pspahn No need to down vote, this is still the correct answer to the question, because you cannot overwrite an xml file like you can overwrite a PHP file just using the codepool. And also, local is loaded first... Please check the file app/Mage.php where you can clearly see that the local code pool is added first.

Comment: @pspahn: what you are referring to is the xml load order, but this is not what the autoloader does. And his question explicitly asks whether you can add an xml file in the local code pool to overwrite a core xml file the same way you can do with PHP files. The answer is no. You can only do this by creating a custom module as pointed out in the references of JamesD

Comment: If we're getting pedantic, then the actual right thing to say is Magento adds the local code pool to PHP's include path such that it has precedence over the community and core code pools.  The autoloader doesn't check anything, it just uses PHP's standard `include`.

Comment: @Alan Storm Agreed. The autoloader 'checking' is of course a metaphor for using the include path. Nethertheless with respect to the question, my answer is still correct ;)